# Rails don't delete association on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to prevent rails from trying to delete from a join table when destroying a record.

So if I have

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end


class Project
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

When I call `user.destroy` rails tries to remove a record from the join table `projects_users`. Can I stop it from doing that? `delete_sql` doesn't seem to.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to be able to use database views to surface complicated relationships as rails associations for reporting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to create another model, `UserProject`, and do the following:

```
class User
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :projects, through: :user_projects
end

class Project
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :users, through: :user_projects
end

class UserProject
  has_many :users
  has_many :projects
end
```

That way, when you call `user.destroy`, it would look up the `:dependent` option supplied to `has_many` in `User` to determine what to do with the associated objects. If you set it to `:nullify`, it deletes the `user` object, but the associated `user_project`s and `project`s **will have their `user_id` foreign key set to `NULL`, and thus are not destroyed.**

[Here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) are the documentations for using `has_many` and [why you should prefer not to use has_and_belongs_to_many](http://blog.flatironschool.com/post/35346328762/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this works. Since my join model is a view, trying to nullify project_id is as bad as trying to delete the row in the join table. I also disagree with that blog post for this example (as much as I love Avi).

Comment: In that case, you can always save the ``project_id`` back to the database using the ``after_destroy`` callback, but this method only works if you create a new model for ``UserProject``, since you can't do any callbacks on the join table.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you understand what I mean by a database view. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL) and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createview.html.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are trying to say that your join table is essentially a stored query, and you want this query to not sync itself when the parent record gets destroyed. I think this is more of a database question than a Rails issue, and I'm not familiar with database manipulation.

Comment: Exactly, my join table is essentially a stored query. I want rails to not attempt to modify it, which seems like a rails thing. I could write a rule for the view to discard update attempts, but that feels a little backwards (though I'm open to being convinced it's reasonable).